# Non equivalent states shortest word

Tags: dfa

My textbook contains a theorem that if you have a DFA and two states that are not-equivalent, then there is a differentiating word that has length smaller than amount of states in that DFA.

How do we prove this is true?

Answer (score 1):

Use the pigeonhole principle.  Let $w$ be the shortest differentiating word.  Suppose its length is larger than the number of states of the DFA.  Consider the sequence of states traversed on input $w$.  What can you say about them?  (Use the pigeonhole principle.)

Comment: well, it doesn't necessarily have to be the case that a pair of states is repeated, since one state could just loop to itself, except let's say the last letter in an input word w that is equal in length to the number of states. For the other state, we continuously transition to another state. In that case, no pair of states is repeated.

Comment: @KevinWu, right, so applying the pigeonhole principle to *pairs* of states doesn't work.  What else could you apply it to?